# How to show quicklaunch bar on second monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar, quicklaunch

I've got a quicklaunch folder setup and on my taskbar, but it will only show on the main taskbar. I would like it on both monitors. I tried dragging it much like moving the main taskbar to whatever monitor you want, but that did not work. I dont want the system tray on my second monitor, just the quicklaunch bar and my open application icons.

Main Taskbar: https://prnt.sc/unbyic

Second Monitor Taskbar: https://prnt.sc/unbys9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When utilizing multiple monitors, Windows 10 provides options like duplicate or extend and so on. Only duplicate will give the exact same display (including task bar) to the second monitor. But if you choose extend the displays, it will extend actual working area to the second monitor, a primary or main monitor is set up as well.

Although the Taskbar is available on both the monitors, but the primary one is more functional and accessible and some areas(like cortana and quick launch bar)cannot be displayed on the second monitor. It seemed to be the distinction between the main display monitor and the extended or second monitor, which is a software design.

If you would like to have some feature change request, you could report from feedback hub built-in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Since Windows doesn't help on this, use [DisplayFusion](https://www.displayfusion.com/). Amazing program. It'll do it once you configure it. (If you'd still like to do this)